# Trying to set up Laravel 4 gives "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Trying to set up Laravel 4 on a Mac. I've installed Composer but when I go to the public folder via XAMPP I get this:

> Warning: require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel-master/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel-master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel-master/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel-master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Comment: a. Go to that destination and check if the file autoload.php exists. b. if it does, check the permission of the directory (you need to have read permission on)

Comment: Forgot my manners. Thanks sorted it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a way to fix it.

Just read this: http://laravel.com/docs/installation and follow the steps in the documentation.

Install composer first, add Laravel to the root of your project and install the composer.json with cmd. This should work.

Comment: So if I'm on shared host (like ipage) and I don't have access to CMD! I can't install Laravel 4?

Comment: Install xampp on your computer, its a localhost server. You can use CMD on your computer and upload the files to your server

Answer (score 16):

You need to provide the following command from your terminal

composer install

it might get stuck due to permission issues, so try with

sudo composer install

I guess this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yup, this is what I did. You may need to resolve some nasty dependencies but the command you ultimately need to run is `composer install` in the root directory of the Laravel project. Then you should be able to run `php artisan serve` to fire up the local server.

Answer (score 7):

in the command prompt try this

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel>composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

laravel need 5.3.7. please check your php version . if its below from mentioned then its will produce like this error
[Server Requirement](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#server-requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your laravel site directory is /srv/example.com/

and your VPS username is "ubuntu". So write this command

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu.www-data /srv/example.com/
```

Most of the time hosting username is "www-data". That time you can write this

```
sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /srv/example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
composer du
composer update
php artisan optimize
```

Hope it will resolve the issue.