# warning error in autoload.php file in laravel

Tags: php

I am trying to run `quickstart-basic-master` but got this error please give me solution

```
Warning: require(D:\xamp\htdocs\quickstart-basic-master\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xamp\htdocs\quickstart-basic-master\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): 
Failed opening required 'D:\xamp\htdocs\quickstart-basic-master\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;D:\xamp\php\PEAR') in D:\xamp\htdocs\quickstart-basic-master\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810425/trying-to-setup-laravel-4-gives-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Please check the installation instructions https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart#installation
I think you need to run 'composer install'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run

```
composer install
```

so it creates your `vendor`directory with all dependencies.